# Should I use Spring restful web service or controllers to generate json?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I have built a web app using Spring 4. The app allows search users, create elements and so on.

The requirements changed. Now I have to deliver search results as json instead of html (but keep html just in case).

The question is, should I use controllers and redirect to a jsp with json/html according a parameter? or use Spring restful web service?(I've never used this and need to learn how to) if I use Spring restful do I have to do the same job I've already did with the web version to generate json?

Comment: It is all about switching view model, if MVN separation is preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It depends on how did you design your previous MVC application.**

My suggestion is follow:

But better to use Spring REST Controller. Mechanism is more or less same like MVC. I assume you have **service** layer for **CRUD** data of your application.

Better to use those **Service** and **Repository** and just create `@RestController` for your application. `@ResponseBody` should be your models which are you returning from controller. And `@RequestBody` will hold the data for generaly `POST, PATCH, DELETE` requests.

Good luck.

Comment: My previous MVC app is designed following MVC rules, my controllers are pretty clean with no more than 34 lines of code. I'll use Spring REST it's not complicated :) ! Thanks!